# python if file does not exist fails

Tags: python

so I have a loop that checks folder if it contains *.zip file

```
for file in glob.glob( os.path.join(rootdir, '*.zip')):
        print "zip", file
        #Check if file does not exist
        if not os.path.exists(file):
            print "No files"
            #return
        else:
            some code
```

Now if file exist else works, but if there is no zip file print does not happen

Any suggestions??
Thank you

Comment: ``glob.glob`` will only return file that **do exist** what are you trying to do by testing if the file exist ?

Comment: "file print does not happen"?  There are two `print` statements.  Can you be more specific?

Answer (score 3):

If there is no zip file in that folder, the for loop never executes.

Just like

```
for i in []:
    print "Hello"
```

doesn't print anything because there are no elements to iterate over.

If you need that error message, you can do this:

```
filelist = glob.glob(os.path.join(rootdir, '*.zip'))
if filelist:
    for f in filelist:
        # some code
else:
    print "No files"
```

Answer (score 3):

If there are no zip files then you are looping over an empty list, try something like this:

```
files = glob.glob( os.path.join(rootdir, '*.zip'))
if len(files) != 0:
    for file in files:
        print "zip", file
        #Check if file does not exist
        if not os.path.exists(file):
            print file, "does not exist"
            #return
        else:
            some code
else:
    print "No files"
```

Answer (score 1):

If no files exist, then your loop won't run at all.  The test os.path.exists(file) will always be true (unless other processes are deleting files as you are running the loop) because otherwise, glob wouldn't list is as a file.

```
files = glob.glob( os.path.join(rootdir, '*.zip'))
for file in files:
        print "zip", file
if len(files) == 0:
        print "no files"
```

Answer (score 0):

The `glob()` file returns any matches it finds. If it finds no matches for the pattern you provide, then it returns the empty list: `[]`. This is different from what the shell glob patterns do! In most shells, `foo*` when no files start with `foo*` will just give the word `foo*` to the command; but that is not what `glob()` does.